# C++/TCP Server - Convenient way of event notification

Tags: c++, tcp

I have created a simple C++ TCP Server application.

Client connects and receives back as a simple echo everything that the client sends to the server. No purpose at all except for me to test the communication.

So far so good. What comes as next task for me is to decide a way of how to send a notification to the server that specific event has started.

Some event examples:

1. Player wrote a message - Server accepts the data sent from the client and recognizes that it's a chat message and sends back data to all connected clients that there is new message. Clients recognize that there is new message incoming.
2. Player is casting spell.
3. Player has died

Many more examples but you get the main idea.

I was thinking of sending all the data in json format and there all messages will contain identifiers like

```
0x01 is message event.
0x02 is casting spell event.
0x03 is player dead event.
```

And once identifier is send server can recognize what event the client is asking/informing and can apply the needed logic behind.

My question is isn't there a better approach to identify for what event the server is notified ?
I am in a search of better approach before I take this road.

Comment: That sounds pretty typical.

Comment: "I was thinking of sending all the data in json format" - Why? That seems extremely wasteful when you can instead send it in a compact binary form.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example of how message should look like? Not codewise.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at standard  iso8583 message, it's a financial message but every message has a processing code that determine what action should be done for each incoming message.

Comment: I've researched in google about it and it looks like it sets a the event code infront. So can you give example of how the message should look like as a string maybe ?

Comment: Here an example 010040000000400000  format of message : 0100 type message 04000000 bitmap that mentioned second field is present 400000 is a processing code base on standard is a numeric with length of 6